# What is different about how xcode looks for sources before and after a build?

Tags: xcode, restkit, code-completion, xcode4.6, codesense

I am having an issue getting code sense to work for a Library (RestKit) that I have installed via cocoa pods. But I will try to keep the question more general to how xcode works underneath.

The situation is that I can consistently do the following to fix code completion:

clean (cmd+opt+shift+k) -> close project -> delete derived data -> restart xcode

And when I have the workspace back open, code completion is working fine. However as soon as I build (cmd+b) code completion breaks, and my header import fails.

So my question is, what is different about how Xcode is resolving these headers before and after a build?

Thanks Much.

Comment: It's always helpful to use the project settings (File > Project Settings) and use "Unique" under "Advanced" to ensure that the build folder is unique.

Comment: @flashfabrixx I have done that already, but thanks for the suggestion.